# How to add default URL in Sections Schema

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have been trying to create a schema for a dynamic section, and use some predefined default URL for some pages but liquid cannot accept it. This is the schema code:

```html
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "My New Section",
  "class": "homepage-section",
  "tag": "section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "section-heading",
      "label": "Section Heading",
      "default": "Default Heading",
      "info": "Meaningful copy in 25 characters or less."
    },
    {
      "type": "url",
      "id": "link-1",
      "label": "Link URL 1",
      "default": "/collections/mycollection"
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "My New Section",
      "category": "My Sections"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

So, for the "type": "url" I try to define the default collection "default": "collections/mycollection" and this is the error message when I try to save the file:

> This file contains the following errors: Error: Invalid schema:
> setting with id="link" default must be a string or datasource access
> path

I tried some different options without success:

"default": "https://testing.myshopify.com/"

"default": "https://testing.myshopify.com/"

"default": "collections/mycollection"

"default": "collections/mycollection"

Please, let me know if there is anyway to handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the documentation regarding the special input type provided by Shopify called [URL](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#url)

According to the documentation, you can only set these 2 URLs by default:

1. `/collections`
2. `/collections/all`

[image]

This is because these are two URLs that are present after the store creates automatically, one is set for all collections list pages and once for all products pages. so Shopify knows these two's have already existed.

So these are two default values that you accept into URL fields into the Shopify schema.

Comment: Thank you @onkar. The document you provided also very complete and I was looking for that long time. I'll point the recommended URL in info field.

Comment: @Valladão glad to know it